# Disable multiple record navigation for sub-form

Tags: forms, ms-access, printing, ms-access-2013

I am working on putting finishing touches on a tool after a developer abruptly quit and left no documentation. I have been able to fix everything except for the following.

I am creating a bar chart using data from a select query:

```
Date     Facility     Bucket     Variance
2/5/15   A            >$10k >90  -2.1234
2/5/15   A            >90        -10.567
...      ...          ...        ...
```

Using the chart wizard, I select Data: Variance, Axis: Bucket, Linked fields: Facility, Date (users can select these from the main form).

The chart itself looks perfectly fine, but in the main form a navigation bar appeared, giving me the option to switch between 6 records. Switching changes the graph in no way, shape or form.

http://i.imgur.com/qq6xiqi.png

While I can disable/hide the bar, whatever thing caused it to believe there were six unique records makes it print the same chart 6 times when printed or sent to PDF.

http://i.imgur.com/la9JBCs.png

Any idea what is causing this, and how I can prevent it?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should add that there are 6 unique values for facility and bucket. Date, Facility and Bucket make up the primary key for their table.

EDIT2: It's the Bucket causing this. Joining a facility filter table with the query did nothing.

EDIT3: Record Source query

```
SELECT tbl_Trending_Data.Date, tbl_Trending_Data.Facility, tbl_Trending_Data.Bucket, IIf([Target] Is Null,Null,[Days]-[Target]) AS Variance
FROM tbl_Facility_Filter INNER JOIN tbl_Trending_Data ON tbl_Facility_Filter.Facility = tbl_Trending_Data.Facility
ORDER BY tbl_Trending_Data.Bucket;
```

Comment: Sounds like your form's record source needs to be amended so that it only results in the 1 record rather 6. Perhaps you could post the record source query? (assuming it is a query)

Comment: Sure thing! Added above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your recordsource query to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tbl_Trending_Data.Date, tbl_Trending_Data.Facility,
tbl_Trending_Data.Bucket, IIf([Target] Is Null,Null,[Days]-[Target]) AS Variance
FROM tbl_Facility_Filter 
INNER JOIN tbl_Trending_Data 
   ON tbl_Facility_Filter.Facility = tbl_Trending_Data.Facility
ORDER BY tbl_Trending_Data.Bucket;
```

You need to limit it to **TOP 1** so that you're only looking at the first row.  That will stop the program from printing multiple records/charts.

Comment: Ah of course, SELECT TOP just for the form's source! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!